# Showing $(X^2-YZ,XZ-X) \subseteq (X,Y)$ as Ideals in $k[X,Y,Z]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals

I'm always feeling like I have a hard time immediately seeing how Ideals in $k[X_1,...,X_n]$ are related (in terms of set-inclusions) etc.

For instance, my naive guess would have been that $(X,Y) \subseteq (X^2-YZ, XZ-X)$. But it's quite the opposite. Thus I've tried to confirm that it's indeed $(X^2-YZ, XZ-X)\subseteq (X,Y)$.

---

### What i've done:

An element in $(X^2-YZ, XZ-X)$ is a linear combination $g_1[X^2-YZ] + g_2[XZ-X]$ for $g_1,g_2\in k[X,Y,Z]$.

Here $[X^2-YZ]$ denotes the polynomial $X^2-YZ$ to avoid confusion with the ideal generated by $X^2-YZ$.

Any element in $(X,Y)$ is a linear combination $h_1X + h_2Y$ for $h_1,h_2\in k[X,Y,Z]$.

One notes that $X^2-YZ \in (X,Y)$ as a linear combination with coefficients $h_1 = X, h_2 = Z$:

$$X\cdot X - Z \cdot Y$$

Analogously for $XZ-X = X(Z-1)$ being a linear combination of $X,Y$ for $h_1 = Z-1, h_2 = 0$:

$$ (Z-1)\cdot X + 0\cdot Y$$

thus we can write $$$$ as

\begin{align*}
g_1[X^2-YZ] + g_2[XZ-X] &= g_1\left[X\cdot X - Z \cdot Y \right] + g_2\left[(Z-1)\cdot X + 0\cdot ​Y\right] \\ &= \left[g_1X + g_2(Z-1) \right]\cdot X - [g_1Z]\cdot Y 
\end{align*}

since $$g_1X + g_2(Z-1), g_1Z \in k[X,Y,Z]$$ we see that $$g_1[X^2-YZ] + g_2[XZ-X] \in (X,Y).$$

---

### My Questions:

So this reasoning is obviously in great length. Therefore my questions are:

what would be the quickest way to see that for arbitrary polynomials it holds that

$$(f_1,f_2)\subseteq (g_1,g_2)\ \text{?}$$

Would the proper (and most efficient) way be to check whether $f_1$ and $f_2$ can both be expressed as linear combinations of $g_1$ and $g_2$?

**Side question:** Is the way I approached this the correct way to think or is there something I haven't noticed?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What 'you have done' is absolutely fine. Regarding question: yes, you just need to show that $f_i$'s are linear combinations of $g_1$ and $g_2$. In practice it might not always be easy to determine as in your particular example.

Comment: Thanks to both of you guys. It seems as if my approach was reasonable, even if quite lengthy. But i feel like it was a good exercise indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question:** "I'm always feeling like I have a hard time immediately seeing how Ideals in $k[X_1,...,X_n]$ are related (in terms of set-inclusions) etc. For instance, my naive guess would have been that $(X,Y)⊆(X^2−YZ,XZ−X)$. But it's quite the opposite. Thus I've tried to confirm that it's indeed $(X^2−YZ,XZ−X)⊆(X,Y)$."

**Answer:** You may write $x^2−yz=f_1x+f_2y$ with $f_1:=x,f_2:=−z$ and it follows $x^2−yz∈(x,y)$. Similarly $xz−x=(z−1)x:=gx$ with $g:=z−1$ and hence $xz−x∈(x,y)$. Hence $(x^2−yz,xz−z)⊆(x,y)$.